# How to edit choices with images in Google Script Editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I've got a Google Form which is attached to a spreadsheet and a script. It's got one radio button field. When a choice is made, I want to run the script to remove the choice from the list. So far so good - I've got this working well.

However, when I use images with the choices, the script removes all of the images. Is there a way of not deleting the images? Or at least a way of accessing the images associaed with a Choice to get me started?

Comment: Create a [mcve] and add the code to question.

Comment: Is your form a Google Form or an HTML form that you created yourself?